# Does Assassin's Creed IV have a windowed or fake-fullscreen mode?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Does AC IV finally have a window or borderless-window/fullscreen-window mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, AC4 does not support Windowed Mode or a Borderless Window.

You can try to use [DXWND](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxwnd/) though, which is designed to force those type of games into windowed mode.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever made this is a legend: he made an application that can make AC4 run in windowed mode. You can use it, and it's better than DXWND: 

[Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag Window Mode Patcher](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/1094-assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-window-mode-patcher/).